# How to create new python thread with classes?

Tags: python, multithreading

On the basis of the [SMTPD](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/smtpd.py) component I wrote my own SMTP server with authorization and etc... The last thing I need to do is add message parsing in to new thread when it comes.

So my component consists of two classes: `SMTPServer` and `SMTPChannel`. It works perfectly in one thread like this:

```
def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()

    if pair is not None:
        conn, addr = pair

        logging.info('Incoming connection from ' + str(addr))

        channel = SMTPChannel(config, conn, addr)
```

Log look like this:

```
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~/www/py_email $ python SMTPServer.py
[2015-05-27 11:15:57] [MainThread] INFO: Server started at 192.168.0.103:1026
[2015-05-27 11:16:46] [MainThread] INFO: Incoming connection from ('192.168.0.46', 52423)
[2015-05-27 11:16:46] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '220 SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP'
[2015-05-27 11:16:46] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> EHLO : '*******'
[2015-05-27 11:16:46] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250-SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP Hello *******\n250-SIZE 20480000\n250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> AUTH : 'PLAIN AGFkbWluADEyMzQ='
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] INFO: ('192.168.0.46', 52423) successfully authenticated
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '235 Authentication successful.'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> MAIL : 'FROM:<reply@*******>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> RCPT : 'TO:<destination@*******>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> DATA
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> QUIT
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '221 Bye'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] INFO: Incoming connection from ('192.168.0.46', 52422)
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '220 SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> EHLO : '*******'
[2015-05-27 11:16:47] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250-SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP Hello *******\n250-SIZE 20480000\n250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> AUTH : 'PLAIN AGFkbWluADEyMzQ='
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] INFO: ('192.168.0.46', 52422) successfully authenticated
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '235 Authentication successful.'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> MAIL : 'FROM:<reply@*******>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> RCPT : 'TO:<destination@*******>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> DATA
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250 Ok'
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> QUIT
[2015-05-27 11:16:48] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '221 Bye'
```

But when I add threads like this:

```
def handle_accept(self):
    pair = self.accept()

    if pair is not None:
        conn, addr = pair

        logging.info('Incoming connection from ' + str(addr))

        new_thread = threading.Thread(target=SMTPChannel, args=(config, conn, addr,))
        new_thread.start()
```

The log looks like this:

```
kiril@kiril-X501A1 ~/www/py_email $ python SMTPServer.py
[2015-05-27 11:23:29] [MainThread] INFO: Server started at 192.168.0.103:1026
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [MainThread] INFO: Incoming connection from ('192.168.0.46', 52414)
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [Thread-1  ] DEBUG: <-- '220 SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP'
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> EHLO : '*****'
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [MainThread] DEBUG: <-- '250-SMTP Server 0.1 ESMTP Hello ********\n250-SIZE 20480000\n250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5'
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [MainThread] DEBUG: --> AUTH : 'PLAIN AGFkbWluADEyMzQ='
[2015-05-27 11:23:49] [MainThread] INFO: ('192.168.0.46', 52414) successfully authenticated
```

As you can see `Thread-1` fires only once, then all messages comes back to main thread... May be it has something to deal with class extending as `class MerlinSMTPServer(asyncore.dispatcher):` and `class SMTPChannel(asynchat.async_chat):`

Comment: @abarnert as i said before the `SMTPChannel` is the same as https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/smtpd.py except that it is rewrote as standalone (validate process message method added to it)

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to use threads with an `asynchat` app? What are you trying to accomplish, and why do you think threads will help? If you can explain that, maybe we can explain how to actually do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix `asyncore` and threads like this. The whole point of an `asyncore`/`asynchat` application is that there's an event loop around `select` that handles all of your sockets, and makes calls to the various handlers. That all happens on a single thread. See the intro to the [`asyncore`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/asyncore.html) documentation, which explains this.

Starting a new `asynchat` channel on another thread doesn't do any good. That just means that it registers itself with the event loop from another thread. (Which isn't actually thread-safe, so you're just getting lucky if it works.) After that, the event loop, and the dispatching to the channel's handlers, all happens on the main thread.

If you want to use multi-threading, don't use `asyncore`. If you want to use `asyncore`, don't use multi-threading.

Comment: So as I understood if I using `asyncore/asynchat` I don’t need to think about threads as it deals itself or I need to rewrite the whole app in order to it would run faster without `asyncore/asynchat` but with threads ? Sorry if I’m not so clear, but I'm new to the Python.

Comment: @user1692333 Well, it doesn't deal with _threads_ itself; it deals with concurrency in a different way (using an event loop). Rewriting it with threads would probably not make it faster (Al hough it depends on what kind of work you're actually doing). Rewriting it with a better event loop might make it faster. But is it actually too slow in the first place? If so, what part is making it slow?

Comment: It not just about the speed, but I receive a lot of emails with a videos/image files which may be heavy. So I just want to parse each in parallel, not one by one.

Comment: @user1692333: You usually do that by using a reactor (what `asyncore`/`asynchat` is) for receiving input data on a single thread, and then farm out the actual parsing work to a pool of threads or processes. (Which one? If there's a huge amount of data to be passed to each task, you want to use threads, but if there's a lot of CPU-bound work in the tasks, you _need_ to use processes; usually those two rules are enough to decide.) But you can't parallelize the reactor itself.

Comment: @user1692333: The traditional way to do this for email processing is to have an SMTP daemon that just dumps files somewhere, and processing daemons that watch for files to process. But you can do this all within Python—I believe in the `smtpd` module it's the `process_message` method that you'd want to hook into. For example, you can have a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` in the server object, its `process_message` just does `self.executor.submit(self.background_process_message, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data)`.

Comment: @user1692333: (Python 2.7 doesn't have the `futures` module, but there's [a backport on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures).)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I now understand where my problem was. Already done. Thanks a lot.